# How to show that a local finite dimensional algebra is basic from definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

A basis algebra is an algebra $A$ such that $e_i A \not\simeq e_j A$ for any $i \neq j$, where $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is a complete set of primitive orthogonal idempotents. A local algebra is an algebra with only one maximal right ideal. How to show that a local finite dimensional algebra is basic from definition? Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume that the algebra is unital. Does a complete set of primitive orthogonal idempotents always exist (in finite dimensional unital algebras)?

Comment: @Berci, thank you very much. Yes, the algebra $A$ is unital.

Comment: @Berci, it seems that if $A$ is local, then $A$ has only two idempotents $0, 1$ and $A = 1A$. So by definition, $A$ is basic. Is this true?

Comment: do you mean basic algebra, not basis algebra?

Comment: @LJR Your comment answers your question. You can post it and accept it, so that it gets removed from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is local, then $A$ has only two idempotents $0,1$ and $A=1A$. So by definition, $A$ is basic.